# ExceptionHandling with TestNG

Tags: java

I referred the below link - http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/ to test exceptions using TestNG. How do I print the message from the calling method? For eg, when `orderBo.save(null);` is called, how do I print - `Order is empty!`

Comment: Unclear what you mean; do you want to test the contents of the expected exception's error message?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That's exactly what I want.

Comment: @fge - Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use, along the `expectedExceptions` parameter to the `@Test` annotation, the `expectedExceptionsMessageRegEx`. However, this becomes quite a messy annotation:

```
@Test(
    expectedExceptions = MyException.class,
    expectedExceptionsMessageRegEx = "^regex for message here$"
)
public void testWhatever() 
{
    codeThatRaisesSomeException();
}
```

And note that the parameter value, as the parameter name suggests, is a regular expression...

Rather than that, why not just do this:

```
@Test
public void testWhatever()
{
    try {
        codeThatRaisesSomeException();
        fail("No exception thrown!");
    catch (MyException e) {
        assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "the expected message here");
    }
}
```

Ultimately, that is a matter of tastes; yours truly finds the latter more readable...

Comment: that should be ```expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp```